# Concatenating Selected Checkboxes into a single row

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

As the title suggests, I'd like to concatenate selected checkboxes into a single row in my table.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{
        jCheckBox1.getText(),
        jCheckBox2.getText(),
        jCheckBox3.getText(),

    });
}
```

This is what I had in mind:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teWyz.png]

What I had imagined happening was when the user selects corresponding checkboxes, the program would note it and concatenate it in to a single column on the jTable. I would eventually like to use this to interpret the data based on job type.

obviously, this didn't work. I'd appreciate your help!

This is supposed to be my pet project for our family business, since I was trying to get back into coding.

Comment: Did you has used the GridViewLayout?

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate into a single column"? Please be a bit more descriptive. And @jhonatan2760 what do you mean by "GridViewLayout" and what does that have to do with Swing JTables?

Comment: Also Gerald, please consider creating and posting a decent [mcve] program.

Comment: will edit this post! Thanks for your response

Comment: A JTable is not designed to contain multiple pieces of data in a single cell. You should have a separate column for each job type. Data is easier to work with as a separate entity and not concatenated together in a string. For example, what happens if you ever want to unselect a checkbox?